# PCA-like analysis for dataset that has both categorical and continuous variables

Tags: dataset, statistics

I have a dataset containing a categorical variable and multiple continuous variables. The categorical variables are coded as discrete integers, whereas the continuous variables are just a range of floats. I believe that the variance in my dataset can be almost entirely described by the single categorical variable and one of the many continuous variables. To justify this, I would be interested in using PCA, but I'm not sure the best approach to use when I am considering categorical data. Any suggestions?

Comment: PCA requires you to be able to define meaningful distances between categories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any the dimensionality reduction algorithms (like PCA) that can work with categorical values.

However, an approach that could help you with that is to make a one-hot encoding of your categorical variables (if the number of possible values is manageable. Otherwise, try to pick only the most frequent values and assign the rest to a single variable).

If you are using Pandas DataFrames, [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How many values can the categorical value take?

Maybe make a column for each possible value and have 1 if the column name matches the categorical value, 0 otherwise.

I think that will show up in PCA.

Answer (score 0):

There are several discussions on this in the stats SE. As a starting point: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/5774/232706